# Gradle get dependency programatically without configuration

Tags: gradle

Is there an option to get Maven dependency in Gradle without using custom configuration for it? For example in custom plugin to just obtain dependency provided from extension? Something like

```
class DependencyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("deps", DepsExtension)
        project.task('useDependency') {
            doLast {
        //use Gradle api to resolve dependency without custom configuration
                project.resolve(project.deps.dependency)
            }
        }
    }
}

class DepsExtension {
    def dependency = 'custom:maven:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It is more or less theoretical question, because I was looking for this in the API but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Configuration config = project.configurations.create('myPrivateConfig')
Dependency dep = project.dependencies.create('custom:maven:1.0') {
    exclude group: 'foo', module: 'bar'
}
config.dependencies.add(dep)
Set<File> files = config.files
```

I do a similar thing in a gradle plugin [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-share/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/gradlemavenshare/DependencyShareAction.groovy#L30)

References

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencySet.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html